# Take Correlated Sub-query Out of CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery, case-when

I have an `employee` table in Oracle that can have either 1 or 2 "future" jobs in table `future_jobs`, a business rule of some sort, e.g.

```
| employee_id | job_id | job_start_date | job_end_date |
|-------------|--------|----------------|--------------|
| 1           | 127589 | 12-SEP-2016    | 25-DEC-2016  |
| 1           | 834780 | 26-DEC-2016    | 08-AUG-2017  |
| 2           | 800253 | 20-OCT-2016    | 13-APR-2017  |
```

I have to get the description of each future job by invoking a stored procedure with a specific parameter, e.g. `F1` and `F2`, based on a descending order of `job_start_date`. In example above, for `employee_id = 1`, when the query below is executed for `job_id = 127589` row, since `job_start_date = 12-SEP-2016` is the earliest date among the two rows for `employee_id = 1`, `get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F1')` should be called, and `get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F2')` for `job_id = 834780`.

and for `employee_id = 2`, since there is only one future job, `get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F1')` should be invoked with the query below. Currently, I can pull the relevant information with the following query:

```
select
    emp.employee_id,
    case
        when fj.job_start_date = (select max(job_start_date)
                                  from future_jobs
                                  where employee_id = fj.employee_id
                                  group by employee_id
                                  having count(employee_id) > 1)
        then get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F2')
        else get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F1')
    end job_description,
    fj.job_start_date
    jd.some_additional_columns
from employees emp
join future_jobs fj
    on emp.employee_id = fj.employee_id
join job_details jd
    on  jd.job_id = fj.job_id
    and jd.job_start_date = fj.job_start_date
    and jd.job_end_date = fj.job_end_date
```

.

```
| employee_id |    job_description   | job_start_date |  jd.columns  |
|-------------|----------------------|----------------|--------------|
| 1           | 1st future job desc  | 12-SEP-2016    | ....         | 
| 1           | 2nd future job desc  | 26-DEC-2016    | ....         |  
| 2           | 1st future job desc  | 20-OCT-2016    | ....         |
```

However, I would like to know if there is another way to take the correlated sub-query out of CASE WHEN statement? Is there even a way to do it without using the correlated sub-query? I need to have this done in a single statement rather than using `WITH` clause type solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want window functions:

```
select emp.employee_id,
       (case when fj.seqnum = 1
             then get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F1')
             else get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F2')
        end) as job_description,
       jd.some_additional_columns
from employees emp join
     (select fj.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by fj.job_start_date) as seqnum
      from future_jobs fj
     ) fj
    on emp.employee_id = fj.employee_id join
    job_details jd
    on jd.job_id = fj.job_id and
       jd.job_start_date = fj.job_start_date and
       jd.job_end_date = fj.job_end_date;
```

I'm not 100% sure the logic is exactly correct.  It follows your description and uses `F1` for the first future job.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I updated the description to explain what the query should return. How do you compare the performance of this solution with the one in the question? Under what conditions, partitioning and analytical function perform better?

Answer (score 1):

Actually on second thought you don't even need the max start date and you don't need the nested select to get a row number you can do it right in the case statement with count(*) as a window function.

```
select
    emp.employee_id,
    case
        when COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fj.employee_id ORDER BY fj.job_start_date) > 1
        then get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F2')
        else get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F1')
    end job_description,
    jd.some_additional_columns
from
    employees emp
    join future_jobs fj
    on emp.employee_id = fj.employee_id
    join job_details jd
    on  jd.job_id = fj.job_id
    and jd.job_start_date = fj.job_start_date
    and jd.job_end_date = fj.job_end_date
```

I like Gordon was thinking of window functions but I uses MAX() and COUNT() over to test your conditions of your subselect.  But like him I am not positive I fully understand your desired logic.

```
select
    emp.employee_id,
    case
        when fj.job_start_date = MAX(fj.job_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY fj.employee_id)
          AND COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fj.employee_id) > 1
        then get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F2')
        else get_description(emp.employee_id, 'F1')
    end job_description,
    jd.some_additional_columns
from
    employees emp
    join future_jobs fj
    on emp.employee_id = fj.employee_id
    join job_details jd
    on  jd.job_id = fj.job_id
    and jd.job_start_date = fj.job_start_date
    and jd.job_end_date = fj.job_end_date
```

**Running Count Example**

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (A CHAR(1),P INT)
INSERT INTO @Table (A,P) VALUES ('A',1),('B',1),('C',2),('D',2)

SELECT
    *
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY A) as RunningCount
FROM
    @Table
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I updated the question. Your solution also works. Given that there are two possible cases, we can eliminate `MAX()` and `COUNT()` aggregates and execute something like Gordon came up with.

Comment: True but because his solution is a nested select I'd be curious to see what the performance difference between our solutions is. I'm willing to bet the count() in the case statement will be slightly faster

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do the query without analytic functions.

Comment: Are you thinking about without window functions? Or without the aggregate functions?  Basically you have to either replicate what the aggregate window functions functions do or you have to create a row_number some how. All the other methods would not be as clean nor probably perform as well

Comment: I did just notice that I actually forgot an order by in my answer that only uses COUNT(*)  the order by makes it a running count which is needed

Comment: without the Window Functions. I did notice the missing `order by` statement as it is mandatory in Oracle but no biggie.

Comment: Forgot to say, given that I'm new to partitioning, I was going to ask how your *first query* works as it only takes into the account the total count? I understand how ROW_NUMBER() operates as it returns a row number for each record in the partitioned set, and based on descending order of start dates, the first row for `employee_id = 1` is going to be `job_id = 2`. However, in case of only COUNT(*), when each record is returned, the condition is always going to be true (as the total count is going to be 2), and therefore, `F2` function is always going to be called for both rows!

Comment: correct because I had left off the ORDER BY every value was the same @ 2, but once you add the order by it acts as a running count so the first row that it is true is 1 then the second 2..  I just put an example if you copy and paste into ssms you will get a better understanding.  cheers

Comment: there is one issue with my method of using count and that is if fj.job_start_date is the same for both jobs then the count would get confused again

Comment: Ahh! I was confused about how `ORDER BY` clause works in partitioning. It looks like, if `ORDER BY` is not used, it calculates `COUNT(*)` function call for all the records in the set, therefore, in case of the scenario in OP, the latest `job_start_date` is selected which has `COUNT(*)` of 2 that is going to apply to all the other rows in the set. By doing `ORDER BY`, it would indeed work as a running counter. The underlying system is an Oracle HR module which uses date tracking, and in these systems, the dates would not overlap, so I don't think your corner case will ever occur.